# Conflicting declarations: var adapter: NewsListAdapter, val adapter: NewsListAdapter

Tags: android, kotlin

It is showing : Conflicting declarations: var adapter: NewsListAdapter, val adapter: NewsListAdapter.

Can someone help what is wrong?

```kotlin
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)



        lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
        lateinit var adapter: NewsListAdapter // 


        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this )
        val items = fetchData()
        val adapter  = NewsListAdapter(items)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because you have declared adapter twice . You should declare it once . Either declare it lateinit and assign value to it in the later half or do it the other way .
I am providing you with two methods :

**Method 1 :**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var adapter: NewsListAdapter
private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

//If you are using kotlin synthetics for any reason skip the below line 
recyclerView = view?.findViewById(R.id.yourviewid) 
//Here yourviewid is a placeholder , you have to put the id that you assigned to the recyclerview in your xml

recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this )
val items = fetchData()
adapter  = NewsListAdapter(items)
recyclerView.adapter = adapter

}
    
}
```

Method 2 :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView




override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

//If you are using kotlin synthetics for any reason skip the below line 
recyclerView = view?.findViewById(R.id.yourviewid) 
//Here yourviewid is a placeholder , you have to put the id that you assigned to the recyclerview in your xml


recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this )
val items = fetchData()
val adapter  = NewsListAdapter(items)
recyclerView.adapter = adapter

}
    
}
```

Comment: Comment if you face any issues

Comment: He can't comment. He didn't have 50 points of reputation yet.

Comment: That applies on other's post . Not on self post ig